# gtk text buffer insert waiting to print in text buffer until handler terminates

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Im using following gtk+2.0 API's :
`gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffer, &iter, -1);`
`gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, "text\n", -1);`
in a button handler, the messages in buffer are shown on GUI only when the respective handler finishes its termination, but I need to show the messages immediately.
I have some blocking calls in handler, until these calls gets unblocked and handler gets terminated messages are not shown on GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally widget updates are visible only after the main loop has had the chance to process the events generated by the widget. To force the events to be handled immediately, you can run the needed iterations of the main loop manually, like this:

```
/* update the widget */
...

/* force refresh */
while (gtk_events_pending())
  gtk_main_iteration();
```

This is a fairly common [documented idiom](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-events-pending) often used for widgets that need immediate updates, such as the progress bar. This pattern has a downside, though - running iterations of the GTK main loop will also handle *input* events, even the click of the same button that handled the original click.

If you often need to run the main loop before finishing the handler, you might be incorrectly implementing event-driven code. Ideally there should be no blocking calls in the handler, and if there have to be, they should be run in a dedicated thread.